# Remove duplicates and keep top one record

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I have extracted the titles from the multiple documents in a folder where one document contains multiple titles in one file using nltk library which is working fine. The only issue is that it contains repeating titles such as

Output :

```
 Daily Update (6/20) REDACTED.,
 Daily Update (9/9).,
 Daily Update (10/10).,
 RE: General/ABC Update.
 RE: General/ABC Update RELEASE IN PART BS.
 General/ABC Update.
 RE: General/ABC Article.
 RE: General/ABC Articie.
 Wrap Up for Friday, September 2017.,
 Wrap Up for Monday, January 2018.,
 Wrap Up for Monday, January 2018.
```

My question is can I apply the fuzzy matching to clean it and how? Or
Can I say keep one top record from the file and remove others?

What would be the best way to deal with this?

Here is the code that I applied:

```
from itertools import chain
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordDetokenizer

word_detokenize = TreebankWordDetokenizer().detokenize


tokenized_text = [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(data1)]

sent_idx_with_event= [idx for idx, sent in enumerate(tokenized_text) 
                       if 'Event' in sent or 'Subject' in sent]

window = 1 # If you want 2 sentences before and after.

list1 = []
for idx in sent_idx_with_event:
    start = max(idx - window, 1)
    end = min(idx+window, len(tokenized_text))
    result = ' '.join(word_detokenize(sent) for sent in tokenized_text[start:end])
    #result = result.split(':')[-1] 
    result = re.split("Subject:|Event:", result)[-1]
    result = re.sub(r"Re","RE",result)
    result = re.sub(r"R.E","RE",result)
    result = re.sub(r"Fw","RE",result)
    result = re.sub(r"FW","RE",result)
    result = re.sub(r"Fwd","RE",result)
    result = re.sub(r"REd","RE",result)
    #print(result)
    
    list1.append(result)
print(list1)
```

and at the end I removed duplicates.

I am expecting one result as below:

```
 Daily Update (6/20) REDACTED.,
 Daily Update (9/9).,
 Daily Update (10/10).
 General/ABC Article.
 Wrap Up for Friday, September 2017.,
 Wrap Up for Monday, January 2018.,
 Wrap Up for Monday, January 2018.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you want a single title which is the "best match" for a given input set of titles. We can also use `thefuzz` for this:

```
import thefuzz
import itertools

examples = set((
    "RE: General/ABC Update.",
    "RE: General/ABC Update RELEASE IN PART BS.",
    "General/ABC Update.",
    "RE: General/ABC Article.",
    "RE: General/ABC Articie.",
))

score = {}
for item1, item2 in itertools.permutations(examples, 2):
    #  Go through every permutation
    ratio = thefuzz.fuzz.ratio(item1, item2)
    #  Calculate the levenshtein ratio score
    try:
        score[item1] += ratio
    except KeyError:
        score[item1] = ratio
#  Choose the single entry with the best score (closest match to all inputs)
result = sorted(score, key=lambda x: score[x])[-1]
```

Finally, our output will be `'RE: General/ABC Update.'` This is the single string from `examples` that has the best matching ratio with all other strings in the input set.

Comment: @SNgard Thank you for helping! I tried above code, but it provides single string output as a best match ratio. I have edited my initial code and output for more clarity on what I'm expecting as a final output.

Comment: Ok, thank you for editing your question. That helps me to understand! I don't think string fuzzing is going to be a good solution for you, since your last three examples are very close in Levenshtein distance... The best bet might be to write the logic for each type (General/ABC, Wrap up for, Daily Update, etc) and search until you find which type is used

Comment: Outputs for Daily update first 3 rowsare from seperate documents and last 3 rows wrap up output are also from seperate documents. 
My question is - General/ABC 5 outputs are from one single document . So is it possible to write syntax saying if there are multiple outputs from a single document then keep first else remove others same as we define in a dataframe saying “keep = ‘first’”. But how can I apply it here?